# Add Array of Graphic Controls to Form at RunTime

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, runtime, picturebox

The Question: How do I add many small PictureBox controls to a form at run time without explicitly creating the controls at design time?

I've found hundreds of solutions for adding multiple controls at design time, and a smaller number of examples for adding a single control at runtime, but I've found nothing about adding an array of controls at runtime.

Application constraints:

- Form will have many PictureBox controls with thumbnail images, exact number not known at design time.
- PictureBox[] array (or similar construct) will be indexed by integer idx.
- The maximum number of controls visible at one time is 1000.
- Clicking a button should add a new thumbnail (i.e., PictureBox[idx]).
- Clicking  PictureBox[idx] lets the user select and load an image into that box.
- Thumbnails can be dragged around the form to reorder them.

I'm using a Windows Form App and C#. (I would insert code to show what I've already tried but there are simply too many failed attempts!)

The Questions:

- Where do I put the code to instantiate a new PictureBox?
- What is the syntax for instantiation?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 8 MAY 2022. I have some working code that uses individual picture boxes. When I try to convert to an array, list, etc., the code blows up. It seems that the system never figures out that I am trying to add a new graphic control.

THIS CODE WORKS -- but it uses individual PictureBoxes, which is not what I want.

```
namespace SimplePic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int iconIndex;
        private Button btnAdd = new Button();
        private PictureBox ikon0 = new PictureBox();    // Equivalent to ikons[0]
        private PictureBox ikon1 = new PictureBox();    // Equivalent to ikons[1]

        // Imagine that string[] is the filename returned by a function when the Start button is clicked
        string[] fileNames =
            {
                "D:\\C-Sharp\\Images\\supernova.png",
                "D:\\C-Sharp\\Images\\wormhole.png"
            };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }

    private void designButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Return a different image each time the button is clicked
            switch(iconIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.Controls.Add(this.ikon0);
                    this.ikon0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 111);
                    this.ikon0.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    this.ikon0.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                    this.ikon0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 140);
                    this.ikon0.Image = Image.FromFile(fileNames[0]);
                    iconIndex++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.Controls.Add(this.ikon1);
                    this.ikon1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 111);
                    this.ikon1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    this.ikon1.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                    this.ikon1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 140);
                    this.ikon1.Image = Image.FromFile(fileNames[1]);
                    iconIndex++ ;
                    break;
                default:
                    // Index is higher than number of images
                    iconIndex++ ;
                    label1.Text = "Maximum image count";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THIS CODE BLOCK IS WHAT I WISH WOULD WORK. I'VE KEPT THE SWITCH CONSTRUCT IN ORDER TO HIGHTLIGHT THE CHANGES. I'M BASICALLY JUST REPLACING THE SPECIFIC PICTUREBOX OBJECTS WITH ARRAY ITEMS.

```
namespace SimplePic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button btnAdd = new Button();
        int iconIndex;

        private PictureBox[] ikons = new PictureBox[2];
        //private PictureBox ikon0 = new PictureBox();    // Equivalent to ikons[0]
        //private PictureBox ikon1 = new PictureBox();    // Equivalent to ikons[1]

        // Imagine that string[] is the filename returned by a function when the Start button is clicked
        string[] fileNames =
            {
                "D:\\C-Sharp\\Images\\supernova.png",
                "D:\\C-Sharp\\Images\\wormhole.png"
            };


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    private void designButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // NOTE: IF I COULD GET THIS SYNTAX TO WORK I WOULD REPLACE IT WITH SOME KIND OF ITERATION.
            // I'VE KEPT THE "SWITCH" STATEMENT TO KEEP THE NUMBER OF CHANGES BETWEEN THE TWO VERSION MINIMAL
            switch(iconIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.Controls.Add(this.ikons[0]);
                    this.ikons[0].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 111);
                    this.ikons[0].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    this.ikons[0].BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                    this.ikons[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 140);
                    this.ikons[0].Image = Image.FromFile(fileNames[0]);
                    iconIndex++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.Controls.Add(this.ikon[1]);
                    this.ikons[1].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 111);
                    this.ikons[1].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    this.ikons[1].BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                    this.ikons[1].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 140);
                    this.ikons[1].Image = Image.FromFile(fileNames[1]);
                    iconIndex++ ;
                    break;
                default:
                    // Index is higher than number of images
                    iconIndex++ ;
                    label1.Text = "Maximum image count";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second block of code does not raise any compiler errors, but at run time clicking the Start button yields the exception "Systme.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Looks like a homework to me :) I think your question is off-topic, have you done or tried doing something? Any attempts?

Comment: Define a `List<PictureBox> pictures = new List<PictureBox>()` at form level. Then in a button click, define the PictureBox, and add it to the controls collection of the form as well as the pictures; you also need to attach the event handlers to the control, for example `var p = new PictureBox(); p.Click += pictureBox_Click; p.MouseMove += pictureBox_MouseMove; p.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown; p.MouseUp += pictureBox_MouseUp; this.Controls.Add(p); pictures.Add(p);`. Put the logic in the event handlers. In the event handlers get the PictureBox like this: `var p = sender as PictureBox`.

Comment: Mahmoud... Not homework. I've set myself an objective to learn C#,  this is my first program, and I'm stumped. And as I said, I've tried many different things that don't work. Thanks for answering, though.

Comment: Reza Aghaei, thank you. I will try this idea.

Comment: Added List<PictureBox> ... to form. OK. Added var p = new PictureBox(); this.Controls... and pictures.Add(p) to click event of button. OK. Other 4 lines generate compiler errors. Without them, clicking button does not generate an error but also does not display the new box.

Comment: Error is "name 'pictureBox_Click' does not exist in the current context. I suppose that's another question, i.e., how do I add event code to a control created by code. But the original question is still, how can I display the newly-created picturebox?

Comment: p.Click += pictureBox_Click would underline pictureBox_Click in the IDE.  Put your cursor on that line and press (CTRL + . ).  This will display a menu.  Clicking "Generate Method" from the menu will create a method that is compatible with a PictureBox's Click event.  You'd need to add code to that method for handling what to do when a PictureBox is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  Post a new question for each feature you try to add that you can't figure out yourself or via searching for examples.  Note: This code loads a full image and uses "Zoom" mode to make image appear smaller.  It does not create a smaller image to use as a thumbnail, so it will use more memory.

Place inside your forms class code:

```
    private FlowLayoutPanel _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel;
    private List<PictureBox> Thumbnails { get => _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList(); }


    private const int MAX_THUMBNAIL_COUNT = 1000;  // The maximum number of controls visible at one time
    private const int THUMBNAIL_WIDTH = 80;
    private const int THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT = 80;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This button should really be added to the form in the designer
        var btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Add Thumbnail";
        btn.Name = "AddThumbnailButton";
        btn.Width = 150;
        btn.Click += AddThumbnailButton_Click;  // Clicking a button should add a new thumbnail
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

        _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
        _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Height = this.Height - 100;
        this.Controls.Add(_thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel);
    }

    /// <summary>Clicking a button should add a new thumbnail.</summary>
    private void AddThumbnailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enforce maximum number of controls visible at one time.
        if (Thumbnails.Count >= MAX_THUMBNAIL_COUNT)
        {
            _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(0); 
            // or, if pictureboxes not only control type in FlowLayoutPanel: _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(Thumbnails[0]);


            // or show a messagebox instead:
            //MessageBox.Show("The maximum number of controls visible at one time is 1000.");
            //return;
        }

        var pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Width = THUMBNAIL_WIDTH;
        pb.Height = THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT;
        pb.Click += Thumbnail_Click;
        pb.BackColor = Color.HotPink;
        pb.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    /// <summary>Clicking PictureBox lets the user select and load an image into that box.</summary>
    private void Thumbnail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        ofd.Title = "Select Picture";
        ofd.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.tif";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.SizeMode= PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;                
            pb.Load(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel P. Your code works. I substituted
    this.Controls.Add(pb);
in place of 
    _thumbnailsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pb);
And the picture boxes show up on the form itself. I also added code to relocate the pbs, but that was easy once I understood **how** to add them in the first place.

An oddity: Your code raises two warnings: "Nullability of reference types ... doesn't match the target delegate 'EventHandler' (possibly because of nullability attributes." Any ideas about getting rid of those warnings?

Comment: You'll probably need to change the event handler signatures to specify that object can be null for the sender.  I.e., change "object sender" to "object? sender".

Comment: You might want to play with using a FlowLayoutPanel some, it can clean up a lot of positioning code when it's suitable to use, though I would add the FLP in the designer instead of what I did in the example.  Please mark my answer as the answer if you feel appropriate.